# How to use a list in word2vec.similarity

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I have a word2vec model using pre-trained GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin. The model works fine and I can get the similarities between the two words. For example:

```
word2vec.similarity('culture','friendship')

0.2732939
```

Now, I want to use list elements instead of the words. For example, suppose that I have a list which its name is "tag". and the first two elements in the first row are culture and friendship. So, tag[0,0]= culture, and tag[0,1]=friendship.
I use the following code which gives me an error:

```
word2vec.similarity(tag[0,0],tag[0,1])
```

the "tag" list is a `numpy.ndarray`

the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python6436\Python36\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 992, in similarity
    return dot(matutils.unitvec(self[w1]), matutils.unitvec(self[w2]))
  File "C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python6436\Python36\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 337, in __getitem__
    return self.get_vector(entities)
  File "C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python6436\Python36\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 455, in get_vector
    return self.word_vec(word)
  File "C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python6436\Python36\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 452, in word_vec
    raise KeyError("word '%s' not in vocabulary" % word)
KeyError: "word ' friendship' not in vocabulary"
```

Comment: You should show in your question precisely what `tag` evaluates/prints as – eg `print(tag)` and the output that generates. Then also, `print(tag[0])` and `print(tag[0,0])`. That would make it clear to answerers what you're working with – and might make any problems clearer to you instead, from the act of showing each level of the nested structure separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are some leading spaces in your word ' friendship'.

Could you try this:

```
word2vec.similarity(tag[0,0].strip(),tag[0,1].strip())
```

Comment: Thank you, Omkar! The leading space was exactly the problem!

Answer (score 0):

If tag is,according to your question,is a python-list.Then the problem is you can not index a list with a tuple.
If your list is like [["culture","friendship"],[...]...]
Then your should write word2vec.similarity(tag[0][0],tag[0][1])